# Difference between "résumé" and "CV"

Tags: meaning, differences

What's the difference between *résumé* and *CV*?

When is *résumé* used? And when is *CV* used? Are they equivalent?

Comment: More context may be helpful for better answers. Examples of situations where you were not sure which to use?

Comment: Just a point: the correct spelling is résumé, otherwise it is "resume", like "resume eating".

Comment: @RichardHaven - I think in America résumé now called  'freedom CV'

Comment: @Richard Haven: It's debatable that the correct spelling is "resume" not "résumé". In practice one sees much more often the version without diacritical marks. In English pronunciation is not indicated by the use of diacritical marks (whether it should be is a different issue) and their use usually indicates a word written literally in some other language; resume ceased to be such a more many decades ago. It's perhaps even incoherent to try to indicate English pronunciation via orthography, since it's not habitually done. Certainly "resume" is correct also.

Comment: @RichardHaven Merriam-Webster lists "resume" and "resumé" as acceptable variants of "résumé."

Comment: CV is preferred because you don't have to figure out how to accent the "e".

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In modern English and in the HR sense, they are pretty much used interchangeably and most people assume they mean the same thing.

If you look at their etymology, though, "curriculum vitae" should technically describe what happened over the course of your life, i.e. who your parents were, when and where you were born, upbringing, education, etc., before going into your work experience, while "resume" should sum up your relevant experience and is arguably targeted to your audience, i.e. if it's for an IT job, you'd leave out that you worked as a waiter during your Uni years and you wouldn't think of mentioning your parents (unless maybe their names are Bill Gates or something).

So I would always call what I send for a job application a "resume", but recruiters in my space (IT) typically say "please attach your CV" and mean the same thing. I suppose which you use depends on how pedantic you want to be....

Comment: +1. I still remember the first time I heard one of my former boss said "Send me your CV." "What's CV?" I asked. "It's a resume," he replied.

Answer (score 18):

A simple difference:

CV is WAY LONGER.

Resumes come in a million forms, but they are almost always concise and one page long.

CVs, however, can run on for an untold number of pages-- they usually represent a PhD-holder with a very extensive list of publications, research contributions, and work experience which they wish to share. I've seen CVs go on for a dozen pages.

So in essence, a CV is a bigger, badder resume. 90%+ of people don't need one, and employers don't want to see one.

EDIT: This is only true in the United States. The terms have different meanings in other countries.

Comment: I don't think this answer is wrong, exactly, but rather applicable in only a small subfield of professional life: Academia.

Comment: I am not agree with you. when you pass out from university and going to take jobs at that time you have C.V. and at the time goes after some experience it converted into Resume with field experience. firstly C.V has only detail about curriculum not any field experience. that is why it is called C.V. still in india it is widely used.

Comment: @Java The answer specifically says that this is how the terms differ in the US. How the terms differ in India is irrelevant to agreeing or disagreeing with the answer. Also, if you pass out from university, you're not doing it right.

Answer (score 14):

In my experience, the CV Curriculum Vitae is used more in Britain and is quite thorough, 2/3 pages in length. Whereas a resume is usually a single page, used primarily in the US.

Now, as I said. That's my experience of it having successfully applying for jobs in both places - Others' opinions may differ.

Answer (score 10):

My experience in the US: in academia, *CV*; in business, *resume*.

Answer (score 7):

I think most of the answers so far are speaking about the use of the terms in the US.

In the UK, it's always called a CV. Résumé would be understood, but it's a US English term. The assertion above that CVs are some monstrosity of "an untold number of pages" is just not true here. Standard CVs are almost ubiquitously two pages long, although academic ones may indeed be longer, and ones in other particular fields may be shorter.

Comment: +1 for rightly pointing out that there are regional variations. Most British people would identify `résumé` as 'What Americans call a CV'.

Answer (score 5):

My experience as an academic in the U.S. makes me conclude that the difference between a resume and a CV is primarily functional: a resume introduces an applicant to a prospective employer, while a CV provides an overview of a person's professional career for various purposes, including but not at all limited to a job hunt.

In academia a guest speaker's CV contains the sort of information the audience would like to hear about when the speaker is introduced. It also provides prospective employers with vital information regarding a person's qualifications for a particular assignment, but must typically be accompanied by a statement, usually in the form of cover letter, stating the ways in which the applicant's education and experience qualify the applicant for the position or assignment being sought. A resume, on the other hand, often begins with a description of the position being sought and, unlike most CVs, emphasizes the person's acquired skills and accomplishments relevant to that position.

Both resumes and CVs typically include lists of degrees, job history, awards, professional memberships, and completed projects, presentations, or publications, but the detailed content and format in which these appear may differ greatly from resume to resume depending on its purpose while being more standardized and all-purpose in a CV. A senior scholar often has a CV dozens of pages long but also maintains a set of bioblurbs ranging in length from 100 to 800 words for use in conference programs, lecture announcements, and grant applications.